# A special argument to derive the derivative of the determinant

Tags: matrices, analysis, multivariable-calculus

In [this short note](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hanche/notes/diffdet/diffdet.pdf), in the section "**a better result**" the author says:

> [...] if $\Phi(t)$ is the identity [...] then
>   $$ \frac{d}{d t} \operatorname{det} \Phi(t) = \operatorname{tr} \dot{\Phi}(t) $$
>   when $\Phi(t) = I$.

I do not understand, when $\Phi(t) = I$ is constant, then $\operatorname{det}(I) = 1$ is contant too and the derivative vanishes, so what he means here?

Comment: Presumably the author means that if $\Phi$ is a curve in $M(n, \Bbb R)$ such that $\Phi(0) = I$ then $$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\vert_0 \det \Phi(t) = \text{tr } \dot{\Phi}(0)$$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, never thought of that. Do you understand the rest? I try to follow it, but as I see it the final formula $$ \frac{d}{d t} \mbox{det} \Phi(t) = \mbox{det}(\Phi(t)) \mbox{tr}(\Phi(t)^{-1} \dot{\Phi}(t)) $$ is also valid just for $t = 0$, but what sense has such a formula then?

Comment: You're welcome. For what it's worth, I find the author's notation perhaps unclear at this point. Anyway, the final formula does indeed work globally (here, globally means for all times $t$ for a curve $\Phi$ in $GL(n, \Bbb R)$): For any time $t_0$, apply the above result to $\Psi(t) := \Phi^{-1}(t_0) \Phi(t)$; indeed, by construction $\Psi(0) = I$.

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand, the author assumes $t$ fixed in advance, guess he should have stating something like "Assume $\Phi(t) = I$ for some fixed $t$", then everything would work fine. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.